# How much Salt to Boil Chicken Breast

Tags: chicken, salt, water, chicken-breast

Well you heard right how much salt,! I am a complete noob when it comes to cooking and I have never cooked before. I need to regain my muscle so i desire some boiled chicken.

I want to know how much SALT and WATER is required to boil 500 grams about (1.10 pounds) of chicken breast (bone less).

I am not trying to make soup or anything else with it. Just some good ol' boiled chicken.

Comment: Let's all [be nice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), shall we? (Comments are for requesting more information and suggesting improvements, and definitely not discussion - try the [tour] or the [help] if you need to know something about how the site works, and try [meta] if you have any questions about that.)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to keep a couple of things in mind.  Firstly salt is not necessary at all.  Secondly, boiling a chicken breast will result in dry, chewy chicken. So, I would recommend poaching your chicken breast.  That happens in a liquid that is simmering, just below the boil.  You will need enough to cover the chicken breast.  That liquid can be water, broth...really, any liquid.   In terms of the salt, this is where one might "salt to taste".  A good tasting poaching liquid probably has enough salt, and should do the trick.  Alternately, if using water, add enough salt, maybe a teaspoon at a time, until you like the taste. (Taste before putting the raw chicken in the liquid!)  Of course, the chicken breast itself can also be seasoned before and/or after cooking as well.  Finally, use a thermometer to check your chicken. When it hits 160 - 165 F it is done.